# Mutate Array inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

UPDATED: I am having trouble figuring out how to build an array of results from within a loop of MySQL results. The point is to fill an array of the results with a normalized object from the raw data.
Please help!

```
var people = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    fillOutPeople(rows[i], function (person) {
        people.push(person);
    });
}

console.log(shipments);

const fillOutPeople = (result, callback) => {
    var person = {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.personName,
        address: {
            line1: result.personAdd1,
            line2: result.personAdd2,
            city: result.personCity,
            state: result.personState,
            zip: result.personZip
        },
        familyMembers: []
    }
    getFamilyMembers(result.id, function (result) {
        person.familyMembers = result;
        return callback(person);
    }); 
}

function getFamilyMembers(personId, callback) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM familyMembers WHERE personId=' + personId, 
    function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log({ result: err });
        } else {
            familyMembers = [];
            rows.forEach(function (familyMember) {
                familyMembers.push({
                    id: familyMember.familyMemberId,
                    name: familyMember.name
                });
            });
            return callback(familyMembers);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like that'll work...?

Comment: @JackBashford well except for the `console.log` after the loop with potential asynchronous code

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish OP?

Comment: Your updated code improves the question a lot, now there is only the question why you wish to use a callback at all for this function. Are you sure you are showing all of the code? With the code shown, a map as suggested by Max would be far easier (1 function to take an input parameter, and give a person out)

Comment: Icepickle I am not wanting to update the array I am iterating on though.

Comment: But you are asking for a way to mutate an array :) Your code and the code that Max suggests does pretty much the same, a map will go through every item, and will use the current item as an input argument, and  create a new array from what that function returns. So it will not mutate the original one, but create a new one. For me, the biggest question is why the callback argument (there is no need for it in the code shown (however you might load something from a database in that function, which would again invalidate my statement (as your edit history invalidated most of them ;) ) )

Comment: You were right. I am doing a DB call to retrieve additional information using the mysql package for nodejs. That takes place in the getFamilyMembers function.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe map?

```
const shipments = rows.map(rowItem => rowItem);
```

This iterates the "rows" array and for each row a function is called, in this case it's simply returning the parameter back, but you could always have a method manipulate the data and return whatever you want.

Comment: map does not mutate. If their are other objects with references to the array, they won't notice this change.

Comment: I don't think they want to actually mutate based on the code they posted.